# Two custom keyboard layouts, both ALMOST working in different ways

Tags: customization, xml, keyboard

I have been using the [Programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) keyboard layout for a while, but ran into problems after a poorly-executed tweak of mine which lead to me re-installing version. However, the latest package (marked as beta) does not support KeyBindings that use the control modifier. If I try to modify the Programmer Dovarak bundle with Ukelele, it seems Mac OS X then ceases to recognize it, even after restarts.

I then settled for remaking the Programmer Dvorak layout from Ukelele's built-in Dvorak template. *This* keyboard layout lets me use the Cocoa text shortcuts (^A ^E ^F etc), but I can't do things like dealing with system dialogs (e.g., do a Software Update and press spacebar. In general, outlined button : spacebar :: solid shaded button : enter). In addition, some apps won't let me use Command- shortcuts. For example, I can't use Command-C, -X, or -N in Mental Case while I'm using my remade Dvorak, but I can't use KeyBindings like ^D if I'm using the official Dvorak. *BUT* if I use the normal US keyboard, I get no problems; both control- and command- stuff work fine.

So, my main question is: how do I merge the functionalities of these two layouts? Phrased a different way: Why is it that, given the below XML, I run into the phenomena described above?

1. [a GitHub gist for my recreated Programmer Dvorak layout](https://gist.github.com/1794278#file_from_ukelele.xml)
2. [another gist, posted to save you time from downloading the whole package](https://gist.github.com/1794278#file_official_programmer_dvorak.xml)

Note that the official layout (2nd link above) actually installs itself with a `.bundle` directory in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` whereas I have my recreated layout simply at `$HOME/Library/Keyboard Layouts/name.layout`.

If there's any other information that would be helpful, *please* let me know; I'd be happy to take screenshots or something if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [new version of Programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.o/roland/dvorak/#footnote-mac) that works with key combinations like ⌃A.

> ◊  Option modifier is currently non-functional. Also, you cannot replace a default Roman layout with this one. Control keys should now be functional.

Option worked everywhere I tested, so non-functional could just mean that states under option don't output non-ASCII characters. If you want to disable all default input sources, you can [edit the HIToolBox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout).

In previous versions you could have added a keymap where all keys output a control character like `&#0000;`. See [Control not working in iTerm 2 when using Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75117/control-not-working-in-iterm-2-when-using-programmer-dvorak-keyboard-layout/75140#75140).