# Control not working in iTerm 2 when using Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard, iterm, dvorak

I'm using the Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout and found that the Control key does not work in iTerm 2. Emacs is unusable as a result, and I can't interrupt processes with Ctrl-C. Interestingly, the only thing I have found control to do is that Ctrl-Z still sends SIGTSTP.

I've swapped the Ctrl and Caps-Lock keys at the Mac level, but undoing that has no effect. I use zsh, but running bash doesn't help. Everything works fine in Terminal.

How can I get a working control key?

PS: Reverting back to QWERTY does fix this, but that's not really an option.

Comment: It certainly is not a common problem, so I suspect your custom mapping to be related to this problem. How did you rebind your keys? What keyboard are you using?

Comment: System Preferences->Keyboard->Modifier Keys.

I'm using the built-in Macbook Pro keyboard with the Programmer Dvorak layout.

Comment: Changing keyboard layouts did fix the problem, but the reason I want to use iTerm is the same as the reason I want to use Programmer Dvorak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: There is now a [new version of Programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/#footnote-mac) that works with key combinations like ⌃A, so the instructions below are no longer needed.

> ◊  Option modifier is currently non-functional. Also, you cannot replace a default Roman layout with this one. Control keys should now be functional.

Option worked everywhere I tested, so non-functional could just mean that states under option don't output non-ASCII characters. If you want to disable all other input sources, you can [edit the HIToolBox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout).

Instructions for older versions of Programmer Dvorak:

1. Open `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/Programmer Dvorak.bundle/Contents/Resources/Programmer Dvorak.keylayout`
2. And add this to `modifierMap`:

   ```
   <keyMapSelect mapIndex="3">
     <modifier keys="control anyOption? anyShift?"/>
   </keyMapSelect>
   ```
3. Add this to `keyMapSet`:

   ```
   <keyMap index="3">
     <key code="0" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="1" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="2" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="3" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="4" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="5" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="6" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="7" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="8" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="9" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="10" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="11" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="12" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="13" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="14" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="15" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="16" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="17" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="18" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="19" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="20" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="21" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="22" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="23" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="24" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="25" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="26" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="27" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="28" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="29" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="30" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="31" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="32" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="33" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="34" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="35" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="36" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="37" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="38" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="39" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="40" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="41" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="42" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="43" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="44" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="45" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="46" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="47" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="48" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="49" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="50" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="51" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="52" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="53" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="64" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="65" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="66" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="67" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="69" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="70" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="71" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="72" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="75" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="76" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="77" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="78" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="79" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="80" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="81" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="82" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="83" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="84" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="85" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="86" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="87" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="88" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="89" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="91" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="92" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="96" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="97" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="98" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="99" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="100" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="101" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="102" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="103" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="104" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="105" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="106" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="107" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="108" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="109" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="110" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="111" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="112" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="113" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="114" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="115" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="116" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="117" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="118" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="119" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="120" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="121" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="122" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="123" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="124" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="125" output="&#x0000;"/>
     <key code="126" output="&#x0000;"/>
   </keyMap>
   ```
4. Run `sudo touch /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/` and log out and back in

Comment: Wish I knew what that did, but it works. Thanks a ton!